# Prove for any real number, $|x-6|+x \gt 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Prove for any real number, $|x-6|+x \gt 3$

I think I'm doing the proof wrong but this is what I have on paper:

**Case 1:** let $x-6=0$, then $x=6$

That implies the following: $|6-6|+6 \gt 3$, which is true.

**Case 2:** let $x-6 \gt 0$, then $x \gt 6$

That implies $|x-6|+x \gt x\gt 3$ which is true

**Case 3:** let $x-6 \lt 0$

yeah so this is where I trip up

Comment: You have $|x-6|=6-x$ and you need to prove that $6-x+x>3$, so?

Comment: $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$.

Comment: Note that $|x|+|y| \ge |x-y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x-6<0$ then $|x-6| = -(x-6) = -x+6$

So, $|x-6|+x = 6>3$

Answer (score 2):

If $x-6<0$, then the absolute value of the expression would be $6-x$. The inequality then becomes
$$6-x+x  > 3 \implies 6 > 3$$
Which is true.

Here's what this inequality looks like graphically:

[image]

The purple line is $y=|x-6|+x$, whereas the grey line is $y=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$3-x<6-x\leq|6-x|=|x-6|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Split it in two cases: $$x-6+x>3, ~x-6\geq0\implies x>9/2,~ x\geq 6~~~~(x\in[6,+\infty))$$ $$-(x-6)+x>3,~x-6<0\implies-x+6+x=6>3,~x<6 ~~~~(x\in\left(-\infty,6)\right)$$
Now, $(-\infty,6)\cup[6,+\infty)=\mathbb{R}$